What version Pi is this?
I have been given some Pis and I am trying to identify them so I can get the right software.  I have identified the others, but I am not sure what version this one is.  I have tagged it as Pi2, Is it?


If they have an OS installed, and can be booted, you can get the model number by entering the following command in a terminal: cat /proc/cpuinfo; see this for more details

Unless you have an interest in historical hardware it is of little use. It is unlikely to run any of the current OS due to limited memory. You would probably need to get a copy of one of the original OS.

The model is actually a late Pi Model B and includes a P5 header, Ethernet & 512MB RAM.

You should probably shift your comment to the answer as its a valuable addition.  I hadn't realised quite how old it was.

Actually this is a Raspberry Pi Model A or B Rev 2 with 256 MB of RAM. So one of the oldest Raspis.
The identify your Raspi, the east why is to check the PCB version, which is the line of text under the raspberry on the board. Yours says 2011.12. Entering this number along with "raspberry pi" in a search engine of your choice will lead to one of many pages relating the PCB number to a Raspberry, like e.g. this page
If you have a working Linux-based operating system like Raspberry Pi OS on the Raspi, you can verify the version by opening a terminal and running the command
cat /sys/firmware/devicetree/base/model

This will about the model info.

it is not an A, it's a B as it has two USB's and, more telling, an Ethernet port - also, it's 512MB - the 256MB had only 2011 date

Why the upvotes? The "answer" contains several errors, noted in Comments. In addition the model is actually a late Pi Model B and includes a P5 header.
